# Java inheritance not behaving as expected

Tags: java, inheritance

The following context is needed: The purpose of this way of coding is to avoid `if`-`else` statements and `instanceof`; which is always a bad idea.

I have 3 classes with the following signatures:

```
abstract class A {}
class B extends A {}
class C extends A {}
```

Then I have another class with the following structure:

```
class MyClass {
    private final A model;

    public MyClass(A m) {
        this.model = m;
    }

    public void doSomething() {
        System.out.println(this.model instanceof C); //TRUE!!
        execute(this.model);
    }

    private void execute(A m) {
        System.out.println("noo");
    }

    private void execute(C m) {
        System.out.println("yay");
    }
}
```

And finally the contents of my main:

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    C mod = new C();
    MyClass myClass = new MyClass(mod);
    myClass.doSomething();
}
```

Now the problem; the execute(C) method never gets executed, it's always the execute(A) method. How can I solve this? I cannot change the signature of the execute(A) method to execute(B) since that would give an error saying java "cannot resolve method execute(A)" at MyClass#doSomething.

Comment: This can be solved (at some cost) via the [visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern).

Comment: `A model` -> `execute(A)`, what is a problem?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth hadn't heard of that one yet; it seems pretty interesting indeed..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code illustrates the difference between a static and a dynamic type of an object. Static type is what's known to the compiler; dynamic type is what's actually there at runtime.

The static type of your `model` field is `A`:

```
private final A model;
```

That is, the compiler knows that `A` itself or *some* of its implementations is going to be assigned to `model`. The compiler does not know anything else, so when it comes to choosing between `execute(A m)` and `execute(C m)` its only choice is `execute(A m)`. The method is resolved on the static type of the object.

`instanceof`, on the other hand, understands the dynamic type. It can tell that the `model` is set to `C`, hence reporting the `true` in your printout.

You can solve it by adding a method to `A` and overriding it in `B` and `C` to route to the proper `execute`:

```
abstract class A {
    public abstract void callExecute(MyClass back);
}
class B extends A {
    public void callExecute(MyClass back) {
        back.execute(this);
    }
}
class C extends A {
    public void callExecute(MyClass back) {
        back.execute(this);
    }
}

class MyClass {
    private final A model;

    public MyClass(A m) {
        this.model = m;
    }

    public void doSomething() {
        System.out.println(this.model instanceof C); //TRUE!!
        model.callExecute(this.model);
    }

    public void execute(B m) {
        System.out.println("noo");
    }

    public void execute(C m) {
        System.out.println("yay");
    }
}
```

Note that both implementations call

```
back.execute(this);
```

However, the implementation inside `B` has `this` of type `B`, and the implementation inside `C` has `this` of type `C`, so the calls are routed to different overloads of the `execute` method of `MyClass`.

> I cannot change the signature of the `execute(A)` method to `execute(B)`

Also note that now you can (and should) do that, too, because callbacks are performed to the correct overload based on type of `this`.

Answer (score 5):

Method overloads are resolved at compile time. At compile time, the type of `m` is `A`, so `execute(A m)` gets executed.

In addition, private methods are not overridable.

The solution is to use the Visitor pattern as suggested by @OliverCharlesworth.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Agreed, and the Visitor pattern is the answer, as you suggested.

Comment: Accepted the other answer because it's more detailled, however yours is correct too.

Answer (score 2):

Method overloading is a compile time polymorphism. Thus, for calling method `execute(C)` you need to define your model as `class C`.
It's better to define method `execute()` in `class A` and override it in subclasses.

```
abstract class A {
    abstract void execute();
}
class B extends A {
    public void execute(){};
}
class C extends A {
    public void execute(){};
}
```

And then:

```
class MyClass {
    private final A model;

public void doSomething() {
    model.execute();
}
```

This much better way to use polymorphism to avoid if-else statements and instanceof checking

Answer (score -2):

You are sending object of type C as an object of type A in constructor( you've done upcasting) and assigning it to a reference to type A(which will result in calling only execute(A) method).You could check if the object is a instance of C and depending on the outcome, call the desired method. You could do it like this

```
    public void doSomething(){
        System.out.println(model instanceof C);
        if (model instanceof C) execute((C)model);
        else
            execute(model);
    }
```

Comment: Never use instanceof

Comment: I would not say never but I agree that there's a better way to do it  :)